# Filter Array of [AnyObject] in Swift

Tags: swift, filter, parse-platform

I have an array of `AnyObject` objects in Swift. Each object has attributes of a restaurant, such as name, type, loc, etc. How can I filter the array if I want to keep all objects in the array that contain type: "Sushi".

Sample array of `[AnyObject]` with 2 objects. The filter should keep the first object (type: sushi):

```
[<Restaurant: 0x7ff302c8a4e0, objectId: LA74J92QDA, localId: (null)> {
    City = "New York";
    Country = "United States";
    Name = Sumo Japan;
    Type = Sushi, Japanese, Asian;
}, <Restaurant: 0x7ff302daa790, objectId: 0aKFrpKN46, localId: (null)> {
    City = "New York";
    Country = "United States";
    Name = Little Italy;
    Type = Italian, Pizza;
}]
```

Current Code (but I'm not sure if the filter can search through an array of `[AnyObject]`) :

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurant")
query.whereKey("RestaurantLoc", nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint, withinMiles:50)
query.limit = 2
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if objects != nil {
        println("list of objects of nearby")
        println(objects)
        let searchString = "Sushi"
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Type CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString);

        //Line below gives error: '[AnyObject]' does not have a member named 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate'
        //let filteredArray = objects.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate!)
```

Comment: One question: I understand your array is declared as [AnyObject], but in your case is it safe to assume it contains only elements of type Restaurant?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your array, `objects`, is an array of `PFObject` objects. Thus, to `filter` the array, you might do something like:

```
let filteredArray = objects.filter() {
    if let type = ($0 as PFObject)["Type"] as String {
        return type.rangeOfString("Sushi") != nil
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

---

My original answer, based upon an assumption that we were dealing with custom `Restaurant` objects, is below:

---

You can use the `filter` method.

Let's assume `Restaurant` was defined as follows:

```
class Restaurant {
    var city: String
    var name: String
    var country: String
    var type: [String]!

    init (city: String, name: String, country: String, type: [String]!) {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, assuming that `type` is an array of strings, you'd do something like:

```
let filteredArray = objects.filter() {contains(($0 as Restaurant).type, "Sushi")}
```

If your array of types could be `nil`, you'd do a conditional unwrapping of it:

```
let filteredArray = objects.filter() {
    if let type = ($0 as Restaurant).type as [String]! {
        return contains(type, "Sushi")
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

The particulars will vary a little depending upon your declaration of `Restaurant`, which you haven't shared with us, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, in parse the `type` is set as string. However, the code gives the error: `Use of undeclared type 'Restaurant'`

Comment: Your code sample showed us what appeared to be a class called `Restaurant`. Why don't you show us precisely what the definition of that class/struct looks like and we'll be able to make better suggestions. It's hard to write code for a class we don't have. Or step back and embrace the common theme in all of these answers, that you have a Swift array, and if you will probably want to use `filter` to get the `filteredArray`. The details will vary based upon your implementation.

Comment: I am following the parse documentation to generate a query. The array should be created as `objects` in the current code. http://i.imgur.com/OpM77ZK.png In other words, i didn't specifically create the array anywhere in the code, the query generated the array.

Comment: OK, the log suggested you were dealing with custom objects, but I'm now guessing you're dealing with an array of `PFObject` objects. Frankly, I should have inferred that looking at your `PFQuery` reference. Anyway, if that's the case, you might use something like my revised answer. I'm also now guessing that the `Type` property is not an array of strings, but a comma delimited string.

Comment: Thank you @Rob for the revised answer. I tried it, and it works! Thank you so much. I could not figure this out for a long time. Is it possible for you to explain the two lines just for clarification? `if let type = ($0 as PFObject)["Type"] as String {
        return type.rangeOfString("Sushi") != nil`

Comment: @Rachel The `if let` line (a) casts the individual objects in the array to be `PFObject` objects; (b) gets the `Type` property from that object; and (c) optionally casts that to a string. The `rangeOfString` tests to see if "Sushi" appears anywhere in that string.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the explanation. I have one last question, is it possible for me to store the arrays: `objects` and `filteredArray` as global arrays so that I can call them in other functions? Since the block is run asynchronously, it's being fetched in the background and may not be available immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure if you really mean "global", but, yes, you can definitely update your model to reflect the information you retrieved. That's not at all unusual.

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 3 Solution**

Use the [filter method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688383-filter) on an array.

```
let restaurants: [Restaurants] = [...]
restaurants.filter({(restaurant) in
    return Bool(restaurant.type == "sushi")
})
```

or `return Bool(restaurant.type.contains("sushi"))` if type is an array.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, if the array ***objects*** contains only ***Restaurant***(s) the following code does work.

Lets say Restaurant is something like this:

```
enum RestaurantType {
    case Sushi, Japanese, Asian
}

class Restaurant {
    var type = [RestaurantType]()
    // more properties here...
}
```

First of all lets define an array of Restaurant(s).

```
var restaurants = objects as [Restaurant]
```

Then we can filter it:

```
var sushiRestaurants = restaurants.filter { (restaurant : Restaurant) -> Bool in
    return contains(restaurant.type, .Sushi)
}
```

---

**Update:**
Now I am assuming **objects** is an array of **PFObject**(s)
Just ignore my previous code and try this:

```
var restaurants = objects as [PFObject]
var sushiRestaurants = restaurants.filter { (restaurant : PFObject) -> Bool in
    return contains(restaurant["Type"], "Sushi")
}
```

Maybe it will crash again, the problem is that I don't know the type of Restaurant.Type. I'm trying. Maybe the next error message will provide more useful info.

Comment: The array: `objects` is automatically generated from the parse query `var query = PFQuery(className:"Restaurant")` In order to use the restaurants.filter, do I need to reconstruct the array? Because the current code gives the error `undeclared type 'Restaurant'` when I use it with the array objects

Comment: I found this thread: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1315801 I suspect objects is an array of ***PFObject*** https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html I am going to update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up and for trying! You are both right, that the objects is indeed PFObject. Sorry for the confusion. However, the last line your solution gives this error `Type 'AnyObject!' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'` the error points at the word `contains`

Answer (score 5):

Modification of Rob's answer as Swift 2.0, In swift 2.0 using Rob's code gives error as follows -

```
initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'string'
```

[image]

However it can be solved by using guard statement instead of if-let as below -

```
let filteredArray = objects.filter() {
            guard let type = ($0 as PFObject)["Type"] as String else {
                return false
            } 
            return type.rangeOfString("Sushi") != nil
        }
```

Comment: The difference looks a bit like personal coding style possible by Swift 2.0 features. Please at least explain the difference to @Rob's answer or consider editing Rob's answer adding the Swift 2.0 syntaxed code example (also with some explanation).

Comment: Modified the comment with details.

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution as given below.

```
func filterByCuisineType(list: [Restaurant]) -> [Restaurant]{

    if self.cuisineTypes.count == 0 {
        return list
    }

    let array: [Restaurant] =  list.filter { (restaurant) -> Bool in

        for cuisineName in self.cuisineTypes{

            let isContained: Bool = restaurant.cuisineType.contains(cuisineName)

            if isContained {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    return array
}
```

Comment: This is outdated logic