# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "about:blank" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme about"

Tags: swift, wkwebview, rss-reader

I'm creating a rss reader app and I'm integrating KINWebBrowser but when loaded URL every time it throw a message in title. Code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let item = feedItems[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem
    let url = NSURL(string: item.link)
    let webBrowser = KINWebBrowserViewController()

    webBrowser.loadURL(url)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webBrowser, animated: true)


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are trying to open is the string `"about:blank"`, meaning this is an empty page. They error is due to missing URL scheme, which makes the viewcontroller try open the non-existing `"about"` scheme.

Best way to solve this is to filter the `feedItems` array by removing any item that is not a valid URL. If you want show the blank page anyways, add a proper URL scheme like `http://about:blank`.

Comment: How to do that sorting thing with [feedItem] array?

Comment: Not sorting. Filtering. Run through all elements in the `feedItems` array and remove the elements that contain `"about:blank"`. This is very basic stuff and not a problem related to the web browser functionality.

You can check this post for a specific solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709723/filter-array-of-anyobject-in-swift