# Call on a String as an Array

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have been stuck on a problem for a couple days now and I'm not sure how to word it, so I haven't had much luck searching for an answer hoping you can help!

I have an `array of 20 arrays` which is the same as my `array of 20 strings`, when a button is clicked the array changes to the name of the selected button, I can change it to a string very easily with:

```
newArray = oldArray[0]
```

But cannot find a way to insert the string name as the new array name, if anyone has any advice I'd be glad, thanks!

```
newArray = [oldArray[0]]
```

Just creates an array with one string in, I have been looking for a function something like:

```
newArray = Array(named: oldArray [0])
```

but not sure if it exists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709723/filter-array-of-anyobject-in-swift

Comment: I suppose that the newArray must be of type `[String]`.
How does the declaration (type) looks like for oldArray?

Comment: You also have flatMap if you want to "flatten" something like `[[String]]` into `[String]` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-a-array-of-arrays-in-swift

Comment: So I could flatten the the array into a string? Would that enable me to set the new array name from a string? Edit: thank you for your response!

Comment: Can you give some concrete examples of how you declare and use your array?

Comment: i really not understand what you want , i'm sorry can you explain more

Comment: Also note that in Swift you need to use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` if you want to have a mapping between a string and some value. `Array` can only map sequential integers (0,1,2...) to values.

Comment: I am away from my computer, I shall repost with my example thank you for your time people

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean "new array name?" Array **name**? What is an array name? You talk about having an array of arrays, and then you show code using `oldArray`, and then don't tell us if that is the array of arrays, or show any of your declarations. You need to edit your question to show the way you create oldArray, and you need to explain clearly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert on some specific index then use `insert` like this:

```
var newArr = [String]()
newArr.insert("jogendar", at: 0) /// Removes and returns the element at the specified position.
```

And if you want to add at the end then use `append` like this:

```
var newArr = [String]()
newArr.append("jogendar") ///Adds the elements of a sequence to the end of the array.
```

If you want to change the name of the button when selected then you don't need to maintain the array, you can set the title of button for states like this:

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
btn.setTitle("jogendar_defautl", for: UIControlState.normal)
btn.setTitle("jogendar_selected", for: UIControlState.selected)
```

And when you want to select the button then button name auto change according to selected state:

```
btn.isSelected = !btn.isSelected
```

Comment: That would just insert a string into the array? I would like to make the array to now become the array named "jogendar" but if I use just " "jogendar" " it only returns it as a string? Or am I missing the point? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You cannot change the name of the object(it cannot be possible), But may I know, why you need to change the object name? We can go with key-value pair

Comment: Thank you, could I use the button title as the name of the new array?

Comment: Yes, you can do, but title should be String

Comment: If sender.tag == 0 { btn.setTitle(oldArray [0], for uiControlState.normal} and then newArray = [btn.title]?

Comment: Edited it for you

Comment: "newArray = [btn.title]" , In this, newArray assign with one array element,  You cannot change the object name. You can only change the object values.

Comment: @rmaddy: This is an example to insert in specific position, Thank you I will update it at 0 position

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer as such, you do not provide enough detail for that, but let's see if we can help you onto the right track. You wrote:

> I have been looking for a function something like:
>
> ```
> newArray = Array(named: oldArray [0])
> ```

This does not exist because arrays (and other values) do not have *names*. You appear to be confusing variable names and values, they are very different things. For example, the expression:

```
[0, 1, 8, 27, 64]
```

produces an array *value* containing five elements, it has no *name* it is just a value. The value could be assigned to a variable:

```
var cubes = [0, 1, 8, 27, 64]
```

Now we have a variable with the *name* `cubes` whose current value is the array. The above statement has both declared a variable, `cubes`, given it a type, `[Int]`, and assigned it an initial value, `[0, 1, 8, 27, 64]`. It has not named the value, the value can be copied into another variable:

```
var anotherVariable = cubes
```

After the above you have two variables, `cubes` and `anotherVariable`, each which currently has the same value. Values are **not** *shared*, you can alter one of the values:

```
anotherVariable[0] = 42
```

and now `anotherVariable` contains the value `[42, 1, 8, 27, 64]` while `cubes` still contains the value `[0, 1, 8, 27, 64]`.

OK, back to your question, you wrote:

> I have an `array of 20 arrays` which is the same as my `array of 20 strings`...

What you appear to be describing is something along the lines of:

```
var myArrays = [ [0, 1, 4, 9, 16], [0, 1, 8, 27, 64] ]
var myNames = [ "squares", "cubes" ]
```

and you have buttons with labels `squares` and `cubes`. What you appear to be attempting is to go from a click on a button to an element of `myArrays` via the `myNames` array - which is where you "naming" of values is coming from.

To map a "name" to a "array" you should use a *dictionary*, which is a collection keys, your names, to values, your arrays:

```
let myCollection = [ "squares":[0, 1, 4, 9, 16], "cubes":[0, 1, 8, 27, 64] ]
```

This declares a constant (the use of `let` rather than `var`) dictionary whose keys are strings and values arrays. So you effectively have a collection of "named arrays".

You can now select an array for this collection by name using a statement along the lines of:

```
var currentArray = myCollection[currentButtonTitle]
```

where `currentButtonTitle` has previously been set to the title of the button you clicked.

HTH