# Filter Array of Any Object Based on Object Property

Tags: ios, swift, filter

I am getting a response in this format

```
[
    "1234": {
        "startDate": "1536278400",
        "endDate": "1536796800",
        "playerRank": 1,
        "performance": 100,
        "isProfit": false,
        "members": 1
    },
    "adityaKumar": {
        "startDate": "1536364800",
        "endDate": "1540080000",
        "playerRank": 1,
        "performance": 100,
        "isProfit": false,
        "members": 6
    },
    "madhu60": {
        "startDate": "1539388800",
        "endDate": "1539475200",
        "playerRank": 1,
        "performance": 100,
        "isProfit": false,
        "members": 2
    }
]
```

This response is of type `[string:Any]`. I have to sort the data using the `playerRank` property. I want the output to be of type `[string:Any]`.

How is this possible in Swift?

Comment: You'd probably want to use json parser. Then you can filter.

Comment: @Aditya, `[String: Any]` is a dictionary which is an unordered set of data. You will not get desired data with this format, rather you can have an array of this data with user-name as well in the data-set(dictionary). Then you can apply sorting as array is an ordered set of data.

Comment: One more question that `playerRank` for all the user is same, how can you sort then?

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal I didn’t post full response.  So, there is no solution for this

Comment: @Aditya, if you can change in server-response, then you can convert it at your end, and map the dictionary in array with user-name then you can simply sort the array.

Comment: ok thankyou I will try @AnkitJayaswal

Comment: Hai @Alex can u tell me hoe to do that one

Comment: @Aditya In your response, it is a dictionary and in question, you are referring to it as Array. Are you sure about it?

Comment: hai @Shubham can u explain brief to me I am not understanding.

Comment: @Aditya Your response is representing a dictionary and dictionary are unsorted in nature. But in your question, you want to filter Array of Any Object Based on Object Property. It is a contradiction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter Array of \[AnyObject\] in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709723/filter-array-of-anyobject-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is unsorted

From [swift documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html)

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in an collection with no defined ordering.

However, you can use the `.sorted` method on your dictionary which will give you an array of dictionaries (arrays are sortable).

```
let sorted = dictionary.sorted(by: { ($0.value["playerRank"]) < ($1.value["playerRank"]) })
```

From your original example `sorted` might look like this

```
[
    (
      "key": "madhu60",
      "value": {
         "startDate": "1539388800",
         "endDate": "1539475200",
         "playerRank": 1,
         "performance": 100,
         "isProfit": false,
         "members": 2
      }
   )
   ....
]
```

Comment: hai @Josh can u please explain me briefly

Comment: @Aditya what is that you do not understand?

Comment: after getting this response it is in the format of [key:string, value:Any]. then how to convert this response into [string: any]

Comment: I think the issue is, you do not want a type [string: any] since this is not orderable. You can leave it in this format and use it however you would like for your UI.

Comment: Hai @Josh can u please help how to apply that data to tableview because it is in different format. I am trying but it is showing error

Comment: @Aditya that is a separate question. I recommend you research it and then, if you find no information, ask another question here on SO

Answer (score 0):

Once you parse that `JSON`, you'll get a `dictionary` of type **`[String: [String:Any]]`**, i.e.

```
let data = [
    "1234": [
        "startDate": "1536278400",
        "endDate": "1536796800",
        "playerRank": 1,
        "performance": 100,
        "isProfit": false,
        "members": 1
    ],
    "adityaKumar": [
        "startDate": "1536364800",
        "endDate": "1540080000",
        "playerRank": 1,
        "performance": 100,
        "isProfit": false,
        "members": 6
    ],
    "madhu60": [
        "startDate": "1539388800",
        "endDate": "1539475200",
        "playerRank": 1,
        "performance": 100,
        "isProfit": false,
        "members": 2
    ]
]
```

You can sort this dictionary simply using `sorted` method, i.e.

```
let sortedData = data.sorted { 
    if let rank1 = $0.value["playerRank"] as? Int, let rank2 = $1.value["playerRank"] as? Int
    {
        return rank1 < rank2
    }
    return false
}
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: hai @PGDev I am getting response  in this format [(key: String, value: [String : Any])] but how to this data convert to [string:Any] (OR) I have to assign the data to table view.  [
  (key: "madhu60",
  value: [
    "members": 2,
    "endDate": 1539475200,
    "playerRank": 1,
    "isProfit": 0,
    "startDate": 1539388800,
    "performance": 100
  ])]

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: I am getting response. in the type of  [(key:string, value:Any)] now  I have to assign this response to Tableview. Can u tell me how to assign this format of response.    [
    (
      "key": "madhu60",
      "value": {
         "startDate": "1539388800",
         "endDate": "1539475200",
         "playerRank": 1,
         "performance": 100,
         "isProfit": false,
         "members": 2
      }
   )
   ....
]

Comment: What do you mean by you have assigned it to `tableView`?

Answer (score 0):

I show you a complete answer here.

First convert the response text to a qualified JSON Data.

Second build a customized structure to decode JSON Data to.

Third sort the structure

Last to print back to original response text (You may use a string to have the print result.)

First:

```
            let json = """
    [
        "1234": {
            "startDate": "1536278400",
            "endDate": "1536796800",
            "playerRank": 4,
            "performance": 100,
            "isProfit": false,
            "members": 1
        },
        "adityaKumar": {
            "startDate": "1536364800",
            "endDate": "1540080000",
            "playerRank": 2,
            "performance": 100,
            "isProfit": false,
            "members": 6
        },
        "madhu60": {
            "startDate": "1539388800",
            "endDate": "1539475200",
            "playerRank": 1,
            "performance": 100,
            "isProfit": false,
            "members": 2
        }
    ]
    """.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "{").replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "}").data(using: .utf8)
```

second:

```
    struct Response  {
     struct ResponseData  {
        let name : String
         let startDate : String
         let endDate : String
         let performance : Int
         let playerRank : Int
         let isProfit : Bool
         let members : Int
        }
        var responseData: [ResponseData]
        init (responseData: [ResponseData] = []){
            self.responseData = responseData
        }
    }

     extension Response: Decodable {

        struct DataKey: CodingKey {
                    var stringValue: String
                    init?(stringValue: String) {
                        self.stringValue = stringValue
                    }
                    var intValue: Int? { return nil }
                    init?(intValue: Int) { return nil}

                    static let startDate = DataKey(stringValue: "startDate")!
                    static let endDate = DataKey(stringValue: "endDate")!
                    static let performance = DataKey(stringValue: "performance")!
                    static let playerRank = DataKey(stringValue: "playerRank")!
                    static let isProfit = DataKey(stringValue: "isProfit")!
                    static let members = DataKey(stringValue: "members")!
                }

        public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            var responseData = [ResponseData]()
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DataKey.self)
            for key in container.allKeys {
                let dataContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: DataKey.self, forKey: key)

                let startDate = try dataContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .startDate)
                 let endDate = try dataContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .endDate)
                 let performance = try dataContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .performance)
                 let playerRank = try dataContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .playerRank)
                 let isProfit = try dataContainer.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isProfit)
                 let members = try dataContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .members)
                let each = ResponseData.init(name: key.stringValue, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, performance: performance, playerRank: playerRank, isProfit: isProfit, members: members)
                responseData.append(each)
            }
            self.init(responseData: responseData)
        }
    }

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    var decodedStore = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: json!)
```

third:

```
      decodedStore.responseData.sort{$0.playerRank < $1.playerRank }
```

last:

```
     print ("[")
    for each in decodedStore.responseData {
        print ("""
               \(each.name): {
                        "startDate": \(each.startDate),
                        "endDate": \(each.endDate),
                        "playerRank": \(each.playerRank),
                        "performance": \(each.performance),
                        "isProfit": \(each.isProfit),
                        "members": \(each.members)
                        }
            """)
    }
    print ("]\n")
```